# How to change decimal character (.) to (,)

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to change my decimal in my service or client with generic solution. I'm using .Net WebApi on my service side. And I'm using React.JS with axios on my client side. I have some values about money in my data and they all come with **(.)** if it's decimal. For example, totalDebtAmount = **54.69$** then I want to show it **54,69$**. And for example if the value is much more than 1000, my value should be seen such as **12.456,98$**. Is there any way without **string.replace()** because I have so many pages and I don't want to use 'replace method' for my all values time after time. May I change settings of visual studio or axios library for it? You can see my sample codes and images at below.

```
export const GetDebtList = (SUBSCRIBER_OID_LIST,SUBSCRIBER_INFO_OID,PAYMENT_DATE, 
 SuccessOperation, FailedOperation) => {
 return () => {
 const body = { subscriberOidList: SUBSCRIBER_OID_LIST, subscriberInfoOid:SUBSCRIBER_INFO_OID, 
 paymentDate:PAYMENT_DATE };
 axios.post('/api/GetDebtList', body)
  .then(response => {
    SuccessOperation({ DEBT_LIST: response.data });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    FailedOperation({ DEBT_LIST: null })
  });
}}
```

Here my data and GridPanel

[image: Data which came from service]

[image: My basic Grid Panel On Project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to differentiate between the visual appealing of the number and the value itself.
The value must always be formatted as a floating-point number (using `.`)
How you display your currency, depends on the users' locality.
I would recommend using the `Intl.NumberFormat` API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) or use a currency formatting library like Dinero.js (https://github.com/dinerojs/dinero.js)
Of course, you can already do the formatting on the server-side, but I would recommend doing so on the client.

```
const value = 54.69;

return (
  <>
   {new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(value)}
  </>
)
```

Comment: Actually your solution is totally not what I'm looking for . But I've solved my problem with another way using your solution. That's why I'll accept your answer and Thank you for helping me.